# QSerialPort::readAll() leads to SIGSEGV / SIGABRT if called in a while-loop

Tags: c++, qt, segmentation-fault

I'm communicating with a hardware device using QSerialPort. New data does not emit the "readyRead"-Signal, so I decided to write a read thread using QThread.

This is the code:

```
void ReadThread::run()
{
    while(true){
        readData();
        if (buffer.size() > 0) parseData();
    }
}
```

and

```
void ReadThread::readData()
{
    buffer.append(device->readAll();
}
```

with buffer being an private QByteArray and device being a pointer to the QSerialPort. ParseData will parse the data and emit some signals. Buffer is cleared when parseData is left.

This works, however after some time (sometimes 10 seconds, sometimes 1 hour) the program crashes with SIGSEGV with the following trace:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
[Switching to Thread 0x7ffff3498700 (LWP 24870)]
malloc_consolidate (av=av@entry=0x7fffec000020) at malloc.c:4151
(gdb) bt
#0  malloc_consolidate (av=av@entry=0x7fffec000020) at malloc.c:4151
#1  0x00007ffff62c2ee8 in _int_malloc (av=av@entry=0x7fffec000020, bytes=bytes@entry=32769) at malloc.c:3423
#2  0x00007ffff62c4661 in _int_realloc (av=av@entry=0x7fffec000020, oldp=oldp@entry=0x7fffec0013b0, oldsize=oldsize@entry=64, nb=nb@entry=32784) at malloc.c:4286
#3  0x00007ffff62c57b9 in __GI___libc_realloc (oldmem=0x7fffec0013c0, bytes=32768) at malloc.c:3029
#4  0x00007ffff70d1cdd in QByteArray::reallocData(unsigned int, QFlags<QArrayData::AllocationOption>) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#5  0x00007ffff70d1f07 in QByteArray::resize(int) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#6  0x00007ffff799f9fc in free (bytes=<optimized out>, this=0x609458)
    at ../../include/QtSerialPort/5.3.2/QtSerialPort/private/../../../../../src/serialport/qt4support/include/private/qringbuffer_p.h:140
#7  read (maxLength=<optimized out>, data=<optimized out>, this=0x609458)
    at ../../include/QtSerialPort/5.3.2/QtSerialPort/private/../../../../../src/serialport/qt4support/include/private/qringbuffer_p.h:326
#8  QSerialPort::readData (this=<optimized out>, data=<optimized out>, maxSize=<optimized out>) at qserialport.cpp:1341
#9  0x00007ffff722bdf0 in QIODevice::read(char*, long long) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#10 0x00007ffff722cbaf in QIODevice::readAll() () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#11 0x00007ffff7bd0741 in readThread::readData (this=0x6066c0) at ../reader.cpp:212
#12 0x00007ffff7bc80d0 in readThread::run (this=0x6066c0) at ../reader.cpp:16
#13 0x00007ffff70cdd2e in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#14 0x00007ffff6e1c0a4 in start_thread (arg=0x7ffff3498700) at pthread_create.c:309
#15 0x00007ffff632f04d in clone () at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/clone.S:111
```

I'm not sure how to reproduce the problem correctly, since it appears randomly. If I comment out the "readData()" in my while loop, the crashes do not appear anymore (of course no data can be parsed, then).

Does anyone have a clue what this could be?

Comment: *New data does not emit the "readyRead"-Signal* - I think you should look into this first. QSerialport is derived from QIODevice, so it certainly should be emitting readyRead when data is available.

Comment: I would guess that somewhere you are writing memory outside the bounds of an allocated block, but not in the code you have provided. Have you tried any other tools, such as valgrind or electric fence?

Comment: @TheDarkKnight Yes, I will look at this, of course.

Comment: @DarkFalcon I'm not writing to the device over QSerialPort. Actually, I only need the "readAll"-function from QSerialPort. Running the program with valdrind (over QtCreator) has the interesting effect that the program does not crash (ran for >24h).

Comment: @boltzmann138: If it ran successfully under valgrind, then it sounds like a race condition. One side effect of running under valgrind is that all threads are scheduled on just one virtual CPU, meaning that unlike a real CPU, only one thread can be executing at any given time. Valentin Heinitz is probably on the right track.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the buffer? Could it be, another thread is reading the data from the buffer and clears it afterwards?

Try to lock it (and all other data shared between threads) e.g. with a mutex

```
QMutex mx; // could be also member of the ReadThread class

void ReadThread::readData()
{
    mx.lock();
    buffer.append(device->readAll();
    mx.unlock();
}
```

And do the same in the code which reads and clears the buffer from another thread (I'm not doing the assumption, that this is parseData())

Another possibility could be, parseData() calls some code running in GUI-Thread. This doesn't work in Qt4 and probably also in Qt5

Answer (score 0):

You're using the instance of a `QObject` from multiple threads at once. This generally speaking leads to undefined behavior, as you've just seen. `QSerialPort` will work just fine on the GUI thread. Only once you get it to work there, you can move it to a worker thread.

Note that if the event loop (`app.exec()` call in `main()` or `QThread::run()`) isn't executing, the signals won't be happening. It looks as if you tried to write pseudo synchronous code and have (predictably) failed. Don't do that.

Something like this is supposed to work:

```
#include <QtCore>
#include <QtSerialPort>

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
  QCoreApplication app(argc, argv);
  QSerialPort port;
  port.setPortName(...);
  port.setBaudRate(...);
  ... // etc
  if (! port.open(QIODevice::ReadWrite)) {
    qWarning() << "can't open the port";
    return 1;
  }
  ... // set the port
  connect(&port, &QIODevice::readyRead, [&]{
    qDebug() << "got" << port.readAll().size() << "bytes";
  });
  return app.exec(); // the signals will be emitted from here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that all serial port related objects are initialized and used only in the separate thread. Send received data or parsed events to the UI thread by using signal/slot-mechanism.

Note also that if you inherit QThread in readThread, the constructor may be executed in the UI thread and other functions in the readThread. In that case, start the readThread and run separate initialization function before other functions (for example, by sending proper signal from the UI thread).